# Best content management approach to multi page articles in ExpressionEngine

Tags: matrix, pages, content-elements

We're working on a site where we need to present a multi page article within the front end of the site. Currently this is composed of a number of entries which are set as 'Structure Entries' inside a node.

It's likely that there will be many more articles like this so I'm not comfortable using Structure as a means of 'organising the entries' and beyond the association with each other by nature of their position in the structure tree there is nothing else to 'hold them together' or 'denote an order'.

Articles will vary in length so the native EE approach of a custom field per page isn't going to cut it.

I had thought of perhaps using a Pixel & Tonic Matrix field or Krea Content Elements field, maybe creating a 'custom content element fieldtype' which is a 'Page Break'?

Would love to hear how others have tackled such a challenge?

Answer (score 2):

I think your idea of using Matrix rows or Krea Content Elements to set up separate pages is a good one.

In the past, I've just used a single Wygwam field in conjunction with **[Simple Pagination.](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/simple-pagination)**

> The Simple Pagination plugin makes it possible to split up an entry into an unlimited number of pages by simply entering {pagebreak}

I suppose the nice thing about Simple Pagination compared to a Matrix or Content Elements approach is that the editor could very quickly and easily change the position of page breaks. With a Matrix or Content Elements handling separate pages you'd have to shuffle content between rows in order to change where breaks in your content occur. On the other hand, the Matrix or Content Elements approach is probably a little more client-proof (no chance for typos in entering the page break trigger).

Whatever route you take, since you are using the Structure module you'll inevitably need to use something like [Freebie](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freebie) to prevent the pagination URLs from returning a 404 (ie, use Freebie to set the pagination keyword to an "ignored" and "breaking" segment).

Comment: You might also be able to do the page breaking that Alex is talking about with Grid: http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/paginating-grid-rows

Comment: +1 to this suggestion. The biggest advantage is that the article content is kept together, so you don't have to merge it later down the line if you decide to abandon the multi-page approach.